# How to write operator== to work with implicitly casted/constructed types

Tags: c++, oop, templates, operator-overloading

Why does this not work, since there is an option to 'construct' implicitly?

```
class A {};

template<typename T>
class Type {

public:
    Type() = default;
    Type(T* ptr) {
    }
};

template<typename T>
bool operator==(Type<T> l, Type<T> r) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    Type<A> type(&a);
    bool v = (type == &a); // Does not work
    //bool v = (type == Type<A>(&a)); // That would work
}
```

Why is the implicit construct `Type<A>` with (`&base`, which is `A*`) not used?

How could I write this code to make it work?

Comment: You might need to use something like: `template<typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(Type<T> l, Type<U> r)`.

Answer (score 11):

User-defined conversions are not considered when a function template is checked for viability.

When checking a function template for viability, the implementation tries to deduce template parameters according to template parameter deduction rules. These rules do not involve any type conversions (only type adjustments like removal of qualifiers and references). If deduction fails, the candidate is rejected.

In your case, `T` cannot be deduced from `Type<A>` and `A`. You need both arguments to have the same type `Type<X>` for the deduction to succeed.

Comment: Is "User-defined conversions are not considered when a function template is checked for viability" a result of SFINAE trimming those candidates out of the running before they could (potentially) be applied, later on?

Comment: @Eljay I guess you can state it in these terms. SFINAE is not ever an official term adopted by the standard, just a convenient mnemonic to understand template parameter deduction.

Answer (score 8):

You could make the operator overload a friend function inside your class `Type` as such:

```
template<typename T>
class Type {

public:
    Type() = default;
    Type(T* ptr) {
    }

    inline friend bool operator==(Type<T> l, Type<T> r) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This ensures the operator is actually instantiated from the moment you declare the variable `Type<A> type;`.

In your case it's not instantiated. The compiler could create an instance of the template when you call the operator, but it fails because the template operator declaration can't deduce the arguments `Type<A>` and `A*`. This is actually the error message you get:

> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Type' and 'A*')

As such the implicit construction of `Type<A>` is not even considered because there's no function with the signature `bool operator==(Type<A> l, Type<A> r)` that exists at this point.

Comment: Very nice. You could leave out the `<T>` and just declare it as `operator==(Type l, Type r)` aswell.

Comment: @super Oh interesting, I didn't realise this would work!

Comment: Hm.. Weeird, but.. works :p I still do not fully understand the reason why it does not work 'normally'. Compiler claims that it can see this function:
jdoodle.cpp:17:6: note: candidate: template<class T> bool operator==(Type<T>, Type<T>)
 bool operator==(Type<T> l, Type<T> r) {
      ^~~~~~~~
jdoodle.cpp:17:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
jdoodle.cpp:27:16: note:   mismatched types 'Type<T>' and 'A*'
I tried even explicitly instantiant this operator== with type A, but still - did not help..

Answer (score 1):

You could define the following additional function template:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==(Type<T> l, T* r) {
    return l == Type<T>{r};
}
```

The body of this function template *explicitly constructs* the `Type<T>` object your function template needs in order to properly deduce `T`, so that it can be instantiated.

That way, `type == &a` will result in a call to an instantiation of this function template, which in turn calls an instantiation of your function template `bool operator==(Type<T> l, Type<T> r)`.

Comment: Yes, but too many overloaded operators create other sort of problems :p

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler error states:

> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Type' and 'A*')

and you use typename `T` for both parameters, and that can't work since the types do not match.

Consider using something like this too:

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
bool operator==(Type<T> l, U r)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there was an option to construct implicitly Type<A> from A* so I guess - compiler should see it and use since there was no other option.